# How to make 'SpriteSpin' load a specific image as the first image on load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a 360 degree view with the help of a basic SpriteSpin API. It works fine but I have an additional requirement that I need to load a particular image as the first image/ landing image. 
By **Landing image** I mean that, when the page loads this image should be visible and after that, the animation should continue from that image.

For example:

```js
var imageSrcList = [
  "folder/image_1.jpg",
  "folder/image_2.jpg",
  "folder/image_3.jpg",
  "folder/image_4.jpg",
  "folder/image_5.jpg",
  "folder/image_6.jpg",
  "folder/image_7.jpg",
  "folder/image_8.jpg",
  "folder/image_9.jpg"
];

$('.container').spritespin({
  source: imageSrcList,
  sense: -1,
  animate: false,
  plugins: ['360', 'drag', 'wheel'],
  wrap: isWrap
});
```

In the above example, on load, the 360 degree view starts from the first image i.e `image_1.jpg`. I want the 5th image, `image_5.jpg`, to be seen on page load and continue the animation from there on.

On right swipe i get image_5.jpg --> image_6.jpg --> image_7.jpg and so on.
On left swipe i get image_5.jpg --> image_4.jpg --> image_3.jpg and so on.

Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Why not just put `image_5.jpg` first in the list...?

Comment: but then when i start the swipe animation it will cause a flicker, because it will go from `image_5.jpg` to `image_2.jpg` and continue from there on.

Comment: Well that would happen no matter how you put `image_5.jpg` first, though. Unless you start at 5 then 6, 7, 8, 9, and back to 1 again. This is just simply a case of offsetting the array

Answer (score 0):

`var index = 4;
$('.container').spritespin({
  source: imageSrcList,
  sense: -1,
  animate: false,
  plugins: ['360', 'drag', 'wheel'],
  wrap: isWrap,
  frame : index
});`

Adding **frame : index** did the trick. This index is the index of the image (which we want to load first) in the array imageSrcList